# Big Calendar - How to display a half day in month view

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, react-big-calendar

I am using Big Calendar (https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar) in my react application, and I have problem to show only half of day for event in month view in Big Calendar component.

For example:
Event starts on **06.04.2021** at **12:00**, and ends on **09.04.2021** at **12:00**

Default behaviour:
[image]

Output should looks like this:
[image]

PS: In this scenario, it is easy just move it by CSS combination of position relative and right/left property. Complications occurs when event cover more weeks like this:
[image]

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: That does not seem to be possible to do in react-big-calendar. It seems to be binary, either a day is included or it isn't included. Even for single-day events, it covers the whole day. Edit: my comment only concerns the "month" view. You can absolutely do this in e.g. the "week" view.

Comment: The above comment is exactly correct. The "month" view has no concept of any time period shorter than a day

Comment: Ah, i know about option to do it in week view, but I would like to achieve it in month view. Ok nevermind, thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing this is not possible in any version of fullCalendar (or derivatives such as react big calendar). The "month" view has no concept of any time period shorter than a day.